# React: Inputs not updating different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list where in each `li` there is radio inputs to choose from.

Whenever I select an option, all the inputs in all the other elements are updating with the same option.
I included a unique `id` and a unique `name` as mentionned in **React docs** to regroup each group and make it separate but it didn't work.

**I want to be able to select every element separately in the list. How to do so ?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sun-i2khx?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Eric"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Jonathan"
    }
  ];

  const handleChangeSelected = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
    console.log(event);
  };

  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState("option1");

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                <div className="users">{item.name}</div>
                <p />{" "}
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option1"
                  checked={Selected === "option1"}
                  onChange={handleChangeSelected}
                />
                <label for="huey">Option 1</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option2"
                  checked={Selected === "option2"}
                  onChange={handleChangeSelected}
                />
                <label for="dewey">Option 2</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option3"
                  checked={Selected === "option3"}
                  onChange={handleChangeSelected}
                />
                <label for="louie">Option 3</label>
              </div>
              <br />
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sun-i2khx?file=/src/App.js

*What I tried so far but didn't work to target the input to the corresponding `id`*

```
  function handleSelected(e, id) {
    setSelected({
      ...Selected,
      [id]: Selected[id]
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you put `selected` in each object of list array ?

Comment: @DEEPAK What do you mean ? [You can check my code here here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sun-i2khx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I checked that is why I am asking why not just put a selected key in each object of array!

Comment: like  {
      id: "1",
      name: "John",
      selected: "option1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Eric",
      selected: "option2"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Jonathan",
      selected: "option1"
    }

Comment: if you put this way handling would be easy enough

Comment: You are suggesting to replace `checked` it's that is ? Still I will be having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put `selected` key in your intiallist array value then you can handle like below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "John",
      selected: "option1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Eric",
      selected: "option2"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Jonathan",
      selected: "option1"
    }
  ];

  const handleChangeSelected = (index, option) => {
    const cloneList = [...list];
    cloneList[index].selected = option;
    setList(cloneList);
  };

  const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                <div className="users">{item.name}</div>
                <p />{" "}
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option1"
                  checked={item.selected === "option1"}
                  onChange={() => handleChangeSelected(index, "option1")}
                />
                <label for="huey">Option 1</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option2"
                  checked={item.selected === "option2"}
                  onChange={() => handleChangeSelected(index, "option2")}
                />
                <label for="dewey">Option 2</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option3"
                  checked={item.selected === "option3"}
                  onChange={() => handleChangeSelected(index, "option3")}
                />
                <label for="louie">Option 3</label>
              </div>
              <br />
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

verify here https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-kirch-fwhpb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you very much! I see you completely changed `handleChangeSelected ` while adding `selected`. Although this is working fine, is there any other method where it doesn't require adding `selected` at all ?

Comment: yes, that would increase few more lines. just like you have mentioned snippet in tried section

Comment: here https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-framework-z3tk2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you again. I see that `checked` is different in some fields, is it on purpose ?

Comment: yes, you have to put some conditions, on the first input my condition says if it has nothing by default set selected to first input

Answer (score 1):

`Selected` state is just one string living above the map function.
Consider declare it inside the map -

```
// refactor your main component
{list.map((item) => (
          <ListItem item={item} />  
))}





// create new ListItem component, Selected state declared here
const ListItem = ({item}) => {
  const handleChangeSelected = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
    console.log(event);
  };

  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState("option1");
  return <li key={item.id}>
              <div>
                <div className="users">{item.name}</div>
                <p />{" "}
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option1"
                  checked={Selected === "option1"}
                  onChange={handleChangeSelected}
                />
                <label for="huey">Option 1</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option2"
                  checked={Selected === "option2"}
                  onChange={handleChangeSelected}
                />
                <label for="dewey">Option 2</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={item.id}
                  name={item.id}
                  value="option3"
                  checked={Selected === "option3"}
                  onChange={handleChangeSelected}
                />
                <label for="louie">Option 3</label>
              </div>
              <br />
            </li>
}
```

Now each mapped item manage its own `Selected` state

Comment: I like this method better because it doesn't require much change in the code. Can you please modify it [here] https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-kirch-fwhpb?file=/src/App.js ? For some reason I have error and I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Edit my answer with comments